# How is Session ID sent to Browser

Tags: session, cookies, encryption, session-cookies

Im learning Session Management and i have two questions for which i could not find answers on the web.

Once the user is authenticated, the Server creates the Session ID and sends it the client (user) in the form of a cookie. This cookie is then subsequently used in request the client sends to the server to identify himself among other users.

Now in HTTPS session, the requests sent between the client and server is secured, as requests from client are encrypted using the Public key and it can only be encrypted  using the Private key which the server only has.

But initially when the server sends the cookie information to the client, it could be intercepted by anyone as even if this cookie which contais the session ID is encrypted using the Private key, it could be decrypted by anyone having the Public key. So, my question is :

1) how does the server make sure that the session ID created by the server is securely sent to the client.

2) I learnt the client sends the cookie for each request it makes to the server. In GET request, how does the client send the cookie information as GET does not include the body .

Answer (score 0):

When HTTPS is used a secure connection is established *before* any HTTP requests are actually sent.

[Transport Layer Security (TLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and its predecessor SSL are not built on top of HTTP, but the other way around. They are one or two layers below HTTP in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). HTTP doesn't care whether the connection that it uses is encrypted or not. The browser just requests resources and sends header information such as cookies along with it.

You can check this yourself. Run a capture software like wireshark and look how the connection is established for a website using HTTP and HTTPS.